# Next post link going to not found on search page template

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I m using wordpress 4.0 and I have create a custom search page template successfully but the problem is that the pagination link next is going to not found what should i do Please Guide Me....

here is my code

```
 <div class="blog-post">
  <?php
  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'paged' => $paged );
  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
  ?>
  <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
  <!-- pagination here -->
  <!-- the loop -->
  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
  <div class="blog-span"><?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
  <?php get_template_part( 'content-search', get_post_format() ); ?>
  <div class="space-sep20"></div>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
   <div class="nav-previous alignleft my-link"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous');?></div>
   <div class="nav-next alignright my-link"><?php next_posts_link( 'Next &raquo;', $the_query->max_num_pages ); ?></div>
   <?php else : ?>
   <div class="blog-span">  
   <header class="entry-header">
    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'weblizar' ); ?></h1>
    </header>
    <div class="entry-content">
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords.', 'weblizar' ); ?></p>
    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Preserving Search Page Results and Pagination**

```
<?php
global $query_string;

$query_args = explode("&", $query_string);
$search_query = array();

foreach($query_args as $key => $string) {
    $query_split = explode("=", $string);
    $search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1]);
} // foreach

$search = new WP_Query($search_query);
?>
```

for more help please refer this link
[Create search template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page)

and serch for this title "Preserving Search Page Results and Pagination"